# Converting asp.net/VB website membership from 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, membership

We had a working website built on framework 2.0 with membership. After we converted it to framework 3.5 using the Visual Studio automated conversion mechanism by opening it in Visual Studio 2008 and following the prompts, the membership system is now broken. Dammit, all we wanted was some newer AJAX.

The rest of the site appears to be functioning fine, but when it comes to logging in or managing security on the site, it fails.

So the errors we receive when trying to manage security via the built-in admin pages, seem pseudorandom; everything from 'user cannot log in to database' to 'this file is being used by another process' to 'there's a problem with your datastore'.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of datastore are you using?  SQL Express MDF file in your App_Data folder?  External SQL Server?  Did you change anything in web.config?

So far as I know, there were no real changes to Membership features between 2.0 and 3.5... I think you've got something else going on.

You *can* rollback your changes and test the old system, right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bryan for your response, but this turned out to be a complete disaster and it's something I would NEVER do again. I just came back to say this to anyone who tries it in the future: "You just made a very bad mistake."

Yes, we ended up rolling back, if that's what you call it when you have to re-get everything from SourceSafe to a completely new directory because there is no auto-rollback feature with the framework conversion, only a backup folder that has been screwed with and dumped into another folder and will never work again because all references are now broken and the web.config has a bunch of illegal entries, and the IIS metabase ended up corrupted, and intermittent database locking caused permissions to be wiped, and around 15 or 20 other problems.... there is no solution to this issue. Not really.

Of course I've personally updated many projects using the Visual Studio upgrade system. But never a website, and never one this complex. And now, never again.   :-)